# header display busy image not working in IE11 its working in IE11 compatibility mode IE8 chrome firefox

Tags: javascript

### GScommon_header_inc.jsp

```
<script>

  function createFromPredecessor(params) {
      var request = "<isa:webappsURL name="b2b/createfrompredecessor.do" xsrfprotection="true"/>";
      request = request + "<%= WebUtil.adoptParamsXSRF("?") %>" + params;
      var myTop = form_input();
        if (typeof isaTop == 'function' && isaTop().header) {
         isaTop().header.busy(parent.form_input);
      }

      myTop.location.href = request;

  }
</script>
```

---

busy.js

```
function busy(frameObject) {

    try {
        with(frameObject.document){
            // get all the stylesheets from the header
            var allStylesheets = this.window.document.styleSheets;

            writeln("<html><head>");
            // add the css sheets
            for(var i = 0; i < allStylesheets.length; i++) {
                writeln('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="' + allStylesheets[i].href + '" />\n');
            }
            // add the rest
            writeln("</head>\n<body><div id='busy'>\n" +
                "<img src='<%=WebUtil.getMimeURL(pageContext, "b2b/mimes/images/busy.gif") %>' alt='<isa:UCtranslate key="b2b.busy.message"/>' />" +
                "<p><isa:UCtranslate key="b2b.busy.message"/></p>" +
                "</div></body></html>");
        }
        frameObject.document.close();
    }
    catch (e) {}
}
```

---

frame.js

```
function isaTop() {

    var tmpWnd = window;
    var lastWnd = tmpWnd;    

    try {
        while (tmpWnd.name != "isaTop" && tmpWnd.parent != tmpWnd) {
             lastWnd = tmpWnd;
             tmpWnd = tmpWnd.parent;
        }
    }    
    catch (e) {
     // this can happen because of domain relaxation!
        tmpWnd = lastWnd;
    }    
    return tmpWnd;
}

function header() {

    return isaTop().header;

}


function work_history() {

    return isaTop().work_history;

}


function form_input() {

    return isaTop().work_history.form_input;

}

function getHistoryFrame() {

    return isaTop().work_history._history;

}

function setHistoryFrameUrl(url) {

    if (isaTop().work_history) {

        if (isaTop().work_history._history) {
            var myFrame = isaTop().work_history._history;
            myFrame.location.href = url;
        }else alert('no history');
    }
    else alert('no workhistory');
}

function closer_history() {

    return isaTop().work_history.closer_history;

}

function documents() {

    return isaTop().work_history.documents;

}

function organizer_nav() {

    return isaTop().organizer_nav;

}


function organizer_content() {

    return isaTop().organizer_content;

}
```

---

---

could you please help me out on that issue ? i need to write header busy till page laoded

Comment: ...So what's your question?

Comment: `var request = "<isa:webappsURL name="b2b/createfrompredecessor.do" xsrfprotection="true"/>";` that won't work **anywhere** - so the code in the question is clearly not the code you are having an issue with

Comment: `with(frameObject.document)` ... I haven't seen `with` used in a *strict*ly long time - how **old** is this code!!

Comment: @ObsidianAge OP says `i need to write header busy till page laoded` - that sounds a bit like a problem description - to be honest, the code in the question doesn't even parse, so it's probably irrelevant

Comment: So, what errors, if any do you get in IE11 when this "doesn't work"™ in the browser *developer* tools console

Comment: @Jaromanda X, in IE11 its keep loading response is not considered no errors in developer tools any alternative for with() function but in chrome its works fine and also its old code written in 2001 year

Comment: when i have removed "isaTop().header.busy(parent.form_input);" from the function createFromPredecessor(params) its working fine but its doesnt display busy image , and also when i removed   with(frameObject.document){
from busy.js its working fine but its doesnt display busy image. i dont know much javascript could you please anybody help me alternative of with statement or some busy image loader code example so i will try myself

Comment: ANYBODY could you please let me know how to write whole html inside Javascript please seen above busy.js i found the issue writeln function is supported by IE11 so please help me out i am new in javascript